# Add/Start/Stop IoT Core application from another application

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-10-iot-core

I would like to add/start/stop/remove an application (IoT Core) just like the web interface or the Power Shell commands: "IotStartup" but from within a C# application running on the IoT Core itself.

Is there a c# API for this or do I have to implement the Power Shell commands inside my application?

Comment: +1 for question since using the ProcessLauncher and PowerShell from inside your IoT-core UWP App will not work due to the sandbox model. You can't run PowerShell except in user mode.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Device Portal API could work for you.

Here are the docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-api-core

Comment: Very interesting link, I'll do some testing before accepting but it looks promising :)

Answer (score 1):

Device Portal APIs are intended for remote management, and may not work from within a UWP against localhost due to loopback restrictions in Windows (to prevent an app from attacking the device it's running on).

That said, the [Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager) class provides installation and removal APIs for apps. To launch an app, you can use [Windows.System.Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher).  Note that PackageManager is a restricted capability, so the app won't be able to go into the Store without special permissions from Microsoft.  It will work in sideloaded scenarios though.

There is no way to close an app from another app with existing APIs.  However, Launching the app using the above, then connecting with an AppServiceConnection to manage it, you can send a "Close" message over the AppServiceConnection that causes the app to close itself.